# crash with local notification flutter -> message_codecs.dart StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

Hello I add local notification on my app, but I have some crash on firebase crashlytics.

Here is my code and error

```
 @override
  void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
   check_notification();
 }

check_notification()async{

FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

if(toggle_notification==false){

  _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll;
}
 else{
  intialize();
  ScheduledNotification_remove();
 }
}



final _localNotificationService = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();


Future<void> intialize() async {
tz.initializeTimeZones();
const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launcher');


final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
DarwinInitializationSettings(
  onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,

  requestSoundPermission: true,
  requestBadgePermission: true,
  requestAlertPermission: true,

);

final InitializationSettings settings = InitializationSettings(
  android: androidInitializationSettings,
  iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,

);

await _localNotificationService.initialize(
  settings,
  // onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification,
    );
           }


       

  Future<NotificationDetails> _notificationDetails() async {
  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
   AndroidNotificationDetails('channel_id', 'channel_name',
    channelDescription: 'description',
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,
    enableVibration: true,
    playSound: true

);

const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
DarwinNotificationDetails(
    presentSound: true,
    presentAlert: true,
    presentBadge: true);


return  NotificationDetails(
  android: androidNotificationDetails,
  iOS: darwinNotificationDetails,
  );
 }


 Future<void> showScheduledNotification(
  {required int id,
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required int seconds}) async {
final details = await _notificationDetails();

await _localNotificationService.zonedSchedule(
  id,
  title,
  body,
  tz.TZDateTime.from(
    DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: seconds)),
    tz.local,
  ),


  details,
  androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
  uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
  UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,

);
}


ScheduledNotification_remove()async{



final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

_flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(1);
_flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(2);
_flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(3);
_flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(4);
_flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(5);


 showScheduledNotification(
      id: 1,
      title: 'title1',
      body: "body1",
      seconds: 1,
 }


showScheduledNotification(
      id: 2,
      title: 'title2',
      body: "body2",
      seconds: 2,
 }


 showScheduledNotification(
      id: 3,
      title: 'title3',
      body: "body3",
      seconds: 3,
 }

 showScheduledNotification(
      id: 4,
      title: 'title4',
      body: "body4",
      seconds: 4,
 }

 showScheduledNotification(
      id: 5,
      title: 'title5',
      body: "body5",
      seconds: 5,
  }
 }
```

---

```
 Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: PlatformException(error, Missing type parameter., null, java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
    at g.c.d.T.a.<init>(:3)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.c.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.loadScheduledNotifications(Unknown Source:25)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.removeNotificationFromCache(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelNotification(Unknown Source:53)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(:2)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:389)
    at j.a.e.a.y.a(Unknown Source:17)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.n.q.i(Unknown Source:11)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.n.q.j(:3)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.n.c.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8205)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
). Error thrown null.
       at StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope(message_codecs.dart:607)
       at MethodChannel._invokeMethod(platform_channel.dart:177)
       at FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:274)
```

---

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4890)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2417)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that led me here was to do with an "Invalid Envelope" error concerning 'Flutter Local Notifications' [FLN] - a package I have used.

In my case, it was a completely new error - everything was fine earlier, however, I had just completed a change of Android icon during which I deleted the default Android icons and changed file names from their default names.

By chance, I went to look at my FLN code, and there I noticed a reference to the default name of the Android notification's icon, and so I changed it to the reflect the new name and icon, and then ran my code again, and then everything was as good as it was before.

In your case, if the cause of your error is the same as mine, then I have noticed that your code refers to a default Android icon name "@drawable/ic_launcher".  This might be the problem on one hand, but on the other, at default my code refers to the mipmap directory (for app icons but not the notification icons).

So please check, are you referring to an icon name that has changed (as I was)?  Or, is is that because you are referring to drawable instead of mipmap that your error has arisen?